# PHP str_replace is undefined

Tags: php, string, replace

I am using php 5.4 and str_replace should be a standard function but when I try and use it it errors out on me:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method stdClass::str_replace()

Here is my php.ini: http://www.mediafire.com/view/uuhn9jhcbnohnod/php.ini

Code Snippit:

```
$id = $decoded->str_replace(" ", "", $origin)->id;
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? I think the issue is related to the way you're calling `str_replace`.

Comment: `str_replace` is just a function. It's not a method of `stdClass` unless you defined it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
$id = $decoded->str_replace(" ", "", $origin)->id;
```

to:

```
$id = str_replace(" ", "", $origin->id);
```

Thus [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is built-in PHP function, you should call it directly and not as method of any object.